# GUI for Dropdown select

Tags: jquery, html, css

When you try to add status in facebook, there is this dropdown list that when user can select to make the status visible to friends, anyone and such. How can i make a similar dropdown list that will have icons and names. I don't like the standard dropdown menu. I want user to click the icon. Upon clicking the icon,the user will have two options to select. My form will be passed to the controller to do the process. Could anyone suggest how can i change the look and feel of a dropdownlist

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try (not like FB): http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 1):

I think `dojo` serves your need Check out [`dojox.form.DropDownSelect`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/form/DropDownSelect.html#dojox-form-dropdownselect)  [`dijit.form.DropDownButton`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/DropDownButton.html) [`dijit.form.Select`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/Select.html)

As Of with jQuery. You can use Search for plugins. I can see one such on http://jonathan.tang.name/files/jquery_combobox/demo.html Plugin on http://plugins.jquery.com/project/image-combobox

Comment: im musing Jquery...any suggestion for jquery instead? :)

Comment: I don't use jQuery Now. However You can do it with dojo with declarative syntax Only. e.g. no Javascript just HTML Like Syntax. Check out the Declarative Examples out There.